# Need to disable mouse right click in Windows?

Tags: windows, hook

I am creating a system tray app which monitors mouse clicks in Windows. I want to disable the right mouse click. My app is based on this [sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).

In the HookCallback method, I tried to do this:

```
if ((MouseMessages)wParam == MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
                    return (System.IntPtr)1;
```

thinking the mpuse event will be not be processed but the context menu of the right mouse click still shows up.

Comment: Why would you want to do this across the whole of Windows? You're basically trying to cripple it.

Comment: I have a very specific need and it's for myself only.

Comment: April 1st is still a very long time from now.

Comment: What does `return (System.IntPtr)1;` do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Mini-Input from [www.mini-tools.com](http://www.mini-tools.com).

Comment: Can you improve this answer? How did it solve your problem? That domain is down btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not handled WM_RBUTTONUP message, that's why the context menu showes up.

Just add this code snippet and check it works...

```
if ((MouseMessages)wParam == MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONUP)                    
    return (System.IntPtr)1;
```

Comment: Most mouse activities happen on the mouse up, not mouse down. Try clicking a button slowly sometime. The biggest exception is when you want to drag.

Comment: What does `return (System.IntPtr)1;` do exactly?